# Output the filename when value is found in array

Tags: json, jq, filenames

I want to output the filename when a value is found in a particular array within a JSON object using `jq`.  I'm essentially trying to use `jq` as a JSON-aware `grep` to find files of interest.

Example JSON data from a file:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "tags": [
      "value1", "value2"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get the filenames when `tags[value1]` exists.

I tried these:

```bash
$ jq '.data.tags | select(any(index("value1"))) | file_name' -- *.json
$ jq '.data.tags | select(. == "value1") | file_name' -- *.json
```

But I receive an error:  "jq: error: file_name/0 is not defined at , line 1"

How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I receive an error: "jq: error: file_name/0 is not defined at , line 1"

The filter is called `input_filename` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input_filename)). Also, with jq 1.6+ you can use the [SQL-Style Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) `IN` to check for the existence of an item within an array.

```bash
jq -r 'select(IN(.data.tags[]; "value1")) | input_filename' -- *.json
```